# Inconsistensy between Get-ChilItem and Test-Path

Tags: powershell, enumeration, bulk

I tried to process each cue files in all subfolders
However, even though I can enumerate all cue fiels, I can not process some of files (probably because of spaces in the path)

Just small example

```
PS Y:\> Get-ChildItem y:\  -Recurse  | where {$_.Extension -ceq '.cue'} | ForEach-Object { Test-Path $_.FullName }
False
False
True
False
True
False
True
False
True
True
```

So, `Get-ChildItem` found item, but `Test-Path` returns that object does not exists. How is it possible?

Comment: Can you output the filenames as well to help point out any patterns?

Comment: If you're worried about spaces, why don't you add quotes? Rule it out. Have you done any trouble-shooting?

Comment: System.IO.File.Exists works as expected PS Y:\> Get-ChildItem y:\  -Recurse  | where {$_.Extension -ceq '.cue'} | ForEach-Object { [System.IO.File]::Exists($_.F
ullName) }
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True

Comment: I found pattern - if path contains [ or ], Test_Path returns False. Solution is to add -LiteralPath. Please close the question

Comment: You can write an answer yourself and accept it or delete the question yourself if you want.

Answer (score 0):

If path contains [ or ], Test_Path returns False. Solution is to add -LiteralPath.